# how to concatenate a date string inside an html element locator with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I have the following line of code in a playwright test using js

```
await page.click('[aria-label="Choose Friday, March 4th, 2022"]');
```

I want to store the date inside a variable like this:

```
let date = "Friday, March 4th, 2022";
```

which I have as

```
await page.click('[aria-label="Choose 'date' "]');
```

however in my editor I see the warning

```
',' expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate a string use `+`

```
await page.click('[aria-label="Choose ' + date + ' "]');
```

Comment: Or a cleaner/more intuitive version I find is with using template literals:
`await page.click(\`[aria-label="Choose ${date}]\`);`